# Apply function to each element in array and store result in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a function `toWords` which converts a integer into a word

e.g. `toWords(500, tableWords)` gives `fivehundred`

I have an array of numbers `h = (1..999).to_a`, and I want to go through this array and convert each number into a word and store it in a new array. My current attempt to do this is:

```
h = (1..999).to_a
Lh = h.each do |i| toWords(i, tableWords) end
```

However, the contents of `Lh` is simply the integers from 1 to 999 and not the output of my `toWords` function.  How do I do this? I'm thinking of something along the lines of `sapply` in R.

Even better is if my new array Lh can have two columns, the first column containing the integers in number format, and the second column would be the corresponding number in words.

Thank you!

Comment: [Array.map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get your two columns, you can do the following

```
(1..999).map {|x| [x, toWords(x, tableWords)]}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per Cicada's comment, the answer is:

```
Lh = h.map{|x| toWords(x, tableWords)}
```